# How can I random the item in Flatlish?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to random the posts like this
[image]

i had tried like this also

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
        this.state.posts.length)]}
      // numColumns={1}
      horizontal={false}
      keyExtractor={(elem, index) => elem.id}
      renderItem={(elem)=>(
        <PostListItem style={{ marginTop: 10, width: "100%" }}
        title={elem.item.tieude}
        description={elem.item.mota}
        image={{uri:`${elem.item.imgUrl}`}}
      />
      )}/>
```

but no work!
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a single element from `posts` to the `FlatList` as `data`. You should be passing the whole list instead, but shuffle it first. If that is what you actually need to do, then you can consult [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array).

Comment: yes! successful with shuffle, many thanks